# Cannot use pre-bundled map in newest SDK version (Android)

Tags: android, skmaps, skobbler-maps

I've been using Skobbler SDK version 2.5.1 to pre-bundle a map on my app. When I wanted to upload my app to the Play store, I was required to upgrade to the latest SDK version - 3.0.2, due to libpng's security flaws, and now I cannot seem to understand how the mechanism works...
I've followed the tutorial in the "How to" section https://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android in the same way I've done for the previous version: In my apps "assets" folder, I've inserted the old "SKMaps.zip" file, which contains both the required package files and the meta files

[image: package files]

[image: meta files]

and in my main activity, I've inserted the following code:

```
private void unpackMaps() {
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Just a sec",
            "Unpacking maps, this might take a minute or two...", false, false);
    String mapResourcesDirPath =
            Methods.getMapResourcesDirPath(MyActivity.this)
    SKMapsInitSettings mapsInitSettings = new SKMapsInitSettings();
    mapsInitSettings.setMapResourcesPath(mapResourcesDirPath)
    mapsInitSettings.setConnectivityMode(SKMaps.CONNECTIVITY_MODE_OFFLINE);
    mapsInitSettings.setPreinstalledMapsPath(mapResourcesDirPath +"PreinstalledMaps");
    mapsInitSettings.setCurrentMapViewStyle
            (new SKMapViewStyle(mapResourcesDirPath + "daystyle/", "daystyle.json"));              
    SKMaps.getInstance().initializeSKMaps(getApplication(), this);
}
```

This does not seem to copy the prebundeled map to the apps resource directory, as it did with the code I've had before:

```
    private void unpackMaps() {
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Just a sec",
            "Unpacking maps, this might take a minute or two...", false, false);
    String mapResourcesDirPath =
            Methods.getMapResourcesDirPath(MyActivity.this);
    final SKPrepareMapTextureThread prepThread =
            new SKPrepareMapTextureThread(MyActivity.this,
                    mapResourcesDirPath, "SKMaps.zip", MyActivity.this);
    prepThread.start();
}
```

I've banged my head on this for a long time, any help explaining the new mechanism which supposedly replaces the old `SKPrepareMapTextureThread`would be great

Comment: You can find a modified demo project with a pre-bundle map, on this similar stackoverflow thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41697601/skobbler-sdk-3-0-2-prebundled-map