# Skobbler SDK 3.0.2: prebundled map

Tags: android, skmaps, skobbler-maps

I'm using Skobbler SDK 3.0.2 and I can't load prebundled map.

I prepared the map package for prebundling (SKMaps.zip) following instruction in https://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android. I want to use only a prebundle map in offline mode in my project.

This is my code:

SKMapsInitSettings mapsInitSettings = new SKMapsInitSettings();
             mapsInitSettings.setConnectivityMode(SKMaps.CONNECTIVITY_MODE_OFFLINE);
                mapsInitSettings.setPreinstalledMapsPath(getAssets() +"/SKMaps/PreinstalledMaps");

I get this error when I try to initialize the library:

E/SKMaps: SKPrepareMapTextureThread---- start SKPrepareMapTextureThread 01-17 E/SKPrepareMapTextureThread: Shaders or Common files not found

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p7ls6u50qckbmmb/AndroidOpenSourceDemoGradle%202.zip?dl=0) you can download a modified 3.0.2 Android demo project with the city of Stuttgart (Germany) used as a prebundle map.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when putting SKMaps.zip into assets folder with zipped subfolder /SKMaps/ .. Make sure your zip contains only subfolders and files - not another SKMaps folder